# Automating Postgres Database Backup at Midnight

Tags: postgresql, backup

I own cloud VM to run my DB base web applicaitons on Windows OS. I am looking for a method to backup the database automatically at every midnight. Postgres does not seem to have an automatic scheduler for this task. Is there any way we can automate the DB backup at midnight every day?

Comment: Create a cronjob to for pg_dump

Comment: Sir, Cronjob is for Linux and I am on Windows. Edited the Question to include the OS

Comment: Then use a Scheduled Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, Got it with little Search and mixed soultions from stackoverflow.  It was quick for me so Made a tutorial for others.

PostgreSQL 9.6 does not provide any built-in feature for Automatic Database Backup. Following is the step-wise tutorial for automating DB backup.

**Step 1. Login** into your DB Node VM.

**Step 2. Create pgpass.conf**
**Pgpass.conf** is a text file containing the Database connection details. This must be created manually. Open Command Prompt and type the following commands in the given sequence or place them in a .BAT or .CMD file and execute it

```
CD %appdata%
MD postgresql
CD postgresql
Echo <host>:<port_number>:<db_name>:<password> >> pgpass.conf
```

**%appdata%**  - Is the directory under `C:\Users<Windows_loggedin_user_ID>\AppData\Roaming

**PS**: Don’t mistake the above path with where Postgresql has been installed.

**< host>**  - Hostname will be ***localhost***

**<port_number>** – The default is 5432, else use the port number as configured for your Postgresql

**<db_name>** is the name of the Database that is planned to backedup

**< password>** - Database access password.

**Important Point:** Above values need to be separated or delimited by **Colon (:)** as shown above.

On executing the above commands, `pgpass.conf` file will be created at `C:\Users\<Windows_loggedin_user_ID>\AppData\Roaming`

**Step 3. Create Backup Folder**
A Folder where all the Backed up files will be saved.

```
MD C:\<backup_folder_name>  - Will Create a New Folder For ex MD C:\RakyBackup
CD C:\<backup_folder_name>  - Will Take control that New Folder (C:\RakyBackup)
```

**Step 4. Create Backup Script.** File and name it as `BackupScript.Bat`

Create a `.BAT` File using any text Editor and place the following script in it.

```
@echo off
Set backupPath= C:\RakyBackup
REM Gets the Current System Date into Variable datetime
For /f %%a in (‘powershell –Command “Get-Date –format dd_MMM_yyyy_HHMM”’) do set datetime=%%a
REM Backsup the DB
<path>\Postgresql\<ver_num>\bin\pg_dump -h localhost -p <5432> -U postgres -F c -b -v <db_name> > %backupPath%/DB-Backup_%datetime%h.sql
```

**Step 5. Create a Schedule**
Open **Windows Task Scheduler**. There will three vertical panels. The Left Panel will show *Task Schedule Library*. On the Rightmost Panel select Create Basic Task. Give a Name and *Describe* it in the input textboxes and click next. In the *Trigger*, Select the *Daily* and click Next. Set the Start Date and *Time*. Click Next. In the *Action*, again click Next. The panel will prompt for *Program/Script*. Click *Browse* and Select the `C:\RakyBackup\BackupScript.Bat`. Click Next and then Click *Finish*.

That’s it.

Everyday at the Set time, `BackupScript.Bat` will get triggered and DB will automatically be backed up.

Comment: Are you sure you're using version 9.6 ? That's EOL since November 2021

Comment: Yes sir. It is 9.6. Will be upgrading shortly to latest version.